# Scala empty a list

Tags: list, scala, scala-collections

I have a member variable in a class:

```
val options = mutable.LinkedList[SelectOption]()
```

I latter then populate this list from the database.

At some point I want to refresh the list. How do I empty it?

In java:

```
options.clear();
```

Is there an equivalent in Scala?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Do not use `LinkedList`. That is a low level collection which provides a data structure that can be manipulated at user's will... and responsibility.

Instead, use one of the `Buffer` classes, which have the `clear` method. This method, by the way, is inherited from the `Clearable` trait, so you can just look at classes that extend `Clearable`.